# Docker stats shows different data compared to cadvisor

Tags: docker, cadvisor

I have 2 Docker containers running on Centos machine

for Docker memory monitoring purpose, I have installed "**cadvisor**" on the machine via Docker images

when I compare "**Docker stats**" and "**cadvisor**" value then I see that cadvisor shows ***more*** memory usage than docker stats

for example, the value of memory usage in Docker stats command for one container is *520 MiB* but in cadvisor value is *756 MiB*

Which one is right ?

Comment: Well , both actually show the statistics on that instance  , how are you determining that the stats from cAdvisor co-relates with the stats from docker for the same instance of time.

Comment: I have integrated cadvisor with grafana and created a graph for it. On that graph, I am seeing the different value (756MiB) and on the instance when I typed "docker stats" I see the different value (520MiB) for the same container at the same time

Comment: Grafana would provide you a cumulative stats for a configured period such as 1m,5m etc , i dont think you can compare this with docker stats

Answer (score 11):

According to Docker docs:

> On Linux, the Docker CLI reports memory usage by subtracting page cache usage from the total memory usage.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats/

So, to get from cAdvisor the same value as `docker stats` show, you can use the following expression:
`container_memory_usage_bytes - container_memory_cache`

I tried it out and got exactly the same values as `docker stats` produces.